# Mongod Service exit code 2

Tags: mongodb, shell, service, ubuntu-20.04

**My Problem**

Hi there! When I tried to start and see status I've got an error.

```
skozurak@danny:~$ service mongod start
skozurak@danny:~$ service mongod status
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-07-14 17:54:33 CEST; 3s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 77503 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --auth --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=2)
   Main PID: 77503 (code=exited, status=2)

Jul 14 17:54:33 danny systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Jul 14 17:54:33 danny mongod[77503]: Error parsing YAML config file: yaml-cpp: error at line 32, col>
Jul 14 17:54:33 danny mongod[77503]: try '/usr/bin/mongod --help' for more information
Jul 14 17:54:33 danny systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALID>
Jul 14 17:54:33 danny systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
lines 1-12/12 (END)
```

**What I did**

1. Tried to reinstall
2. Tried to install different versions

Then I added the service to be able to run on server startup.

`skozurak@danny:~$ systemctl enable mongod.service`

I think that problem is in the config file. But I do not know how to fix it there.

`skozurak@danny:~$ sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf`

```
# mongod.conf

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

security:
        authorization: enabled

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

I just changed one line of config as I saw [here](https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-20-04-18-04/)

`skozurak@danny:~$ sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Server
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/mongod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --auth --config /etc/mongod.conf #i changed this line
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
# file size
LimitFSIZE=infinity
# cpu time
LimitCPU=infinity
# virtual memory size
LimitAS=infinity
# open files
LimitNOFILE=64000
# processes/threads
LimitNPROC=64000
# locked memory
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
# total threads (user+kernel)
TasksMax=infinity
TasksAccounting=false

# Recommended limits for mongod as specified in
# http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-settings

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error lies here:

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
```

You can't use any other indentation than **exactly 2 spaces**.